# warm-starting continuous-variable QUBO optimization

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, cplex

I need to warm-start continuous-variable optimization for non-convex problem. The code is in the following:

```
import numpy as np
Sigma = np.array([[1.64376756, 0.7943303 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.86711768,
        0.48220733],
       [0.7943303 , 1.64376756, 0.        , 0.73540312, 0.        ,
        0.7844131 ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.64376756, 0.58192547, 0.28885922,
        0.34554198],
       [0.        , 0.73540312, 0.58192547, 1.64376756, 0.81631243,
        0.        ],
       [0.86711768, 0.        , 0.28885922, 0.81631243, 1.64376756,
        0.        ],
       [0.48220733, 0.7844131 , 0.34554198, 0.        , 0.        ,
        1.64376756]])

Mu = np.array([[2.14365531, 2.31414651, 1.21632667, 2.13364102, 1.97228933,
        1.61216241]])

from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')

x = [mdl.continuous_var(0,1,"x%s" % i) for i in range(len(Sigma))]

objective = mdl.sum([Mu[0][i] * x[i] for i in range(len(Sigma))])
objective -= 2 * mdl.sum(
    [Sigma[i, j] * x[i] * x[j] for i in range(len(Sigma)) for j in range(len(Sigma))]
)


mdl.maximize(objective)

mdl.parameters.qpmethod(3)
mdl.parameters.optimalitytarget.set(3)




mdl.parameters.advance(1)


sol=mdl.solve(log_output=True)

for v in mdl.iter_continuous_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Would you please explain me how to warm-start this model? Thanks

I expect to warm-start the above model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warm Start in CPLEX Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66860193/warm-start-in-cplex-python)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It leads to the the following error: Error: Model.add_mip_start  is only available for MIP problems